# Using data keyword to define types but getting Multiple declaration error

Tags: haskell

I'm in the process of laying out all of the data types for an API wrapper I'm writing. I want to create each type separately, and then combine them under a group so that I can refer to them ambiguously.

E.g.

```
data Bookmark = Bookmark {
  url :: T.Text,
  title :: T.Text
} deriving (Show)

data Note = Note {
  author :: T.Text,
  text :: T.Text
} deriving (Show)

data APIObject = Bookmark | Note
```

This way, I could define something like the following:

```
retrieveFromAPI :: APIObject a => String -> a
```

Where `String` is a URL.

However, when I try to compile this, I get two errors:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( API.hs, interpreted )

API.hs:28:16:
    Multiple declarations of `Bookmark'
    Declared at: API.hs:22:17
                 API.hs:28:16

API.hs:28:27:
    Multiple declarations of `Note'
    Declared at: API.hs:27:13
                 API.hs:28:27
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What should I be doing differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with `APIObject`, you have its constructors as `Bookmark` and `Note`, but those are also constructors for the `Bookmark` and `Note` data types!  Instead you could do something like

```
data APIObject = BM Bookmark | NT Note
```

So now you have a constructor `BM :: Bookmark -> APIObject` and a constructor `NT :: Note -> APIObject`.

---

Alternatively, if you aren't planning on adding more types to `APIObject`, you could just do

```
type APIObject = Either Bookmark Note
```

Since `Either` is defined as

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

so it's isomorphic (the same as) what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hmm, trying to work out the final part of step one. How might those constructors be put together? Would I need to wrap any `Bookmark` / `Note` instance with the appropriate BM / NT type in order to use it generically?

Comment: @Dan yes, you'd have to wrap them up in the additional constructors. Haskell doesn't let you make sum types for free.

Comment: Gotcha. Why can't I do something like this: `data APIObject = Bookmark { url :: T.Text, title :: T.Text } | Note { author :: T.Text, text :: T.Text }`?

Comment: @Dan You actually can, but it's recommended not to.  I personally think it shouldn't be allowed at all unless each constructor has exactly the same fields.  The reason is that you could have `author (Bookmark "www.example.com" "Example")` allowed by the type system, but it would cause a runtime error.  Haskell is meant to make programming safer, not necessarily easier (although it often is), so you should choose a safer route over a "nicer" one.